Прямая речь или дополнение?
У меня два вопроса

Нужно ли оформлять слово "нет" как прямую речь в предложении:

Парень обернулся, внимательно посмотрел на детектива и вдруг выскочил из лифта. В последнюю секунду он выкрикнул «нет» и скрылся за углом.
Я склоняюсь к тому, что нужно, но у автора написано так.
2.
— Они ссорились перед ее отправлением в круиз?
— Спросите меня: «А когда они не ссорились?»
А здесь, мне кажется, наоборот, не надо.
Я права или нет?

Вариант оформления:
Пример 1
Парень обернулся, внимательно посмотрел на детектива — и вдруг выскочил из лифта. В последнюю секунду выкрикнул «нет!»  и скрылся за углом.
Можно восклицательный знак добавить.
Пример 2
— Они ссорились перед ее отправлением в круиз?
— Лучше спросите, когда они не ссорились?
Это выражение иронии, оформлять как авторскую речь не стоит. И желательно предложение максимально упростить, оставив нужное содержание (они ссорятся постоянно).
